# PL/SQL fill tables

Tags: plsql

hello guys it's my first time posting a question but i really need help 
i'am actually new in programming with SQL and i 'am now faced to too many problemes espcially with this exercice 
we had 4 tables 
CLient (**numcli** , name , address,Towncli )
account (**numacc**  , money,#numcli,#numag) 
Agence (**numag**,nameag,townag) 
clientel (**numcli**,**numag**) 
now we had an empty table "STATES" that we need to fill it with informations from the 4 table 
STATES (**numcli**,countaccount,countag,summoney,taux) 
taux must be initialised to 0

values in STRONG means primary key
values in # means foreign key

so i write this BLOC pl/sql but it has a problem

```
DEclare 
cursor c1 is select 
client1.numcli,count(numacc),sum(money),count(numag),taux from account ,states group by (numcli) ;
begin
for c2 in c1
loop
c2.taux:='0' ;
insert into states (numcli,countaccount,countag,summoney,taux) values c2 ;
end loop ;
end ;
```

he said for me oracle values is not enough something like  that 
can any one helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insights:
1) What does in "client1.numcli" client1 stand for? Its misleading. Is this numcli is from table account?
2) Cursor "from" clause, you state two tables, but here is no joining. Mistype? If no, join them;
3) Cursor attributes are listed as numcli,count(numac),sum(money),count(numag) and taux, but in insert statement attributes are listed in different order: numcli, countaccount,countag,summoney,taux;
4) You cant insert into tables like that, with ".. values c2;" in this situation. You need to declare them one-by-one.

As for solution, if you purpose is just to populate table, you can do this:

```
insert into states(numcli,countaccount,countag,summoney,taux) 
select
  acn.numcli,
  count(acn.numacc) countaccount,
  count(acn.numag) countag,
  sum(acn.money) summoney,
  0 taux 
from 
  account acn
group by
  acn.numcli;
```

There is no need for cursor here.
Hope it helps.
Good luck in exploring PL/SQL world!